# google play games achievements reset (every day)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-services

Last week we soft-launched our game and we started getting errors from people. One of the bugs they (all) seem to have is that their achievements are being reset at least every day but sometimes even when restarting our game. The achievements do give the popup when being unlocked, and are even visible in the achievements UI but they keep being reset/removed.

We did know our game behaved like this for our Beta testers, but we assumed this was because everyone that was playing at the time is registered as a Beta tester.

Anyway, we've looked all over the internet to find other people that have the same problem as we do but we came up empty handed. We've checked all our settings in the play dashboard and within our game a dozen times but can't find the problem. Every post is always about resetting achievements, not keeping them.

[image]

One thing that I did notice is that almost 70% of the calls that we make with GPGS is returned by a 4xx response. We are currectly using Unity 5.3.x in combination with GPGS v0.9.32.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening to our achievements?

Comment: Did you follow the correct configuration indicated in [Google Play Games for Unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity)?  Watch this [Youtube demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhSJK-Kn8Uw), you might have missed something during setup.

Answer (score 4):

Alright we've found the answer: we had 2 credentials and apparently used the wrong one in our APK. We switched around the Signing-certificate fingerprint so that the fingerprint in the APK and in play services match and now it's working.

The strange thing is that everything seemed to work and we've never gotten any feedback from google that something was wrong...

Thanks for your attention to this problem!

Comment: we have the same problem, can you elaborate a little more about what was the problem in your case and how you solved that?

Comment: @MateuszKrzaczek did you solve this issue? Now I'm having the same one.

Comment: @Konrad unfortunately no

Comment: @MateuszKrzaczek I fixed this one, I had to add another instance of my game to linked applications to Google Game Services. By another instance I mean exactly the same package but with different signing certificate - it automatically suggested me the one already published - and now it works!