# Android achievements are reset after one day

Tags: android, google-api, google-play, google-play-services

Yesterday I launched my game and I started getting errors from people. One of the bugs they (all) seem to have is that their achievements are being reset at least every day but sometimes even when restarting my game. The achievements do give the popup when being unlocked, and are even visible in the achievements UI but they keep being reset/removed.

I knew my game behaved like this for my Beta testers, but I assumed this was because everyone that was playing at the time is registered as a Beta tester.

Anyway, I've looked all over the internet to find other people that have the same problem but I can't find any solution. I've checked all my settings in the play dashboard(SHA-1 key, package-name, application and achievement ids) and within my game a dozen times but still can't find the problem.

I have multiple activities where users can earn achievements. In all activities I use the `BaseGameActivity` from Google in order to automatically sign in and fix sign in errors.

When I linked my App to the Google Api in the Google Developer Console, I made a mistake and linked my app within a wrong package. Because I can't delete linked apps, i have created a second linked app.
[linked apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/urx1G.png).

One thing that I noticed is that almost 80% of the calls that my app makes with GPGS return a 4xx response.

Does anyone have any idea on why this is happening to my achievements?

**EDIT:** I also get no XP for unlocking achievements. My status codes are
statusCode=SUCCESS and for achievement statusCode=STATUS_OK

[games.applications.played 100% error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGSki.png)

Comment: Are you using the correct credentials as have been encountered in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295924/google-play-games-achievements-reset-every-day)?

Comment: Yes. I checked packagename, meta tags and app_id as well as SHA1-Fingerprint. Followed this [post](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/troubleshooting). When I unlock an achievement i get this status message "STATUS_CLIENT_RECONNECT_REQUIRED" with status code 2. If I click the button again, which unlocks the achievement, I will get this status message "STATUS_OK" and status code 0. But I can definitively see in my google api console that i get 100% of the time 4xx (client errors) on games.achievements.unlock and games.applications.played.

Comment: Sorry to comment on this 2 years old topic. I have exactly the same issue now. Did you figure out the problem?